# Add Hours to Current Date But it excludes the holidays and weekends

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a task to create the T-SQL function to add the 12 hours with current date and time but it should not include any holidays/weekends.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextWorkingDay_Custom] (@givenDate DATETIME)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @DiffDate INT

    DECLARE @workingDate DATETIME
    IF (DATENAME(dw , @givenDate) = 'Friday')
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 3, @givenDate)
    END
    ELSE IF (DATENAME(dw , @givenDate) = 'Saturday')
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 2, @givenDate)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @givenDate)
    END

    SELECT @StartDate = START_DATE
          ,@EndDate = END_DATE
          FROM special_time WHERE START_DATE = @workingDate AND IS_HOLIDAY = 1

    -- Select  count(*) from tblHolidays where holdate = @workingDate
    while ((select count(*) from special_time WHERE START_DATE = @workingDate AND IS_HOLIDAY = 1) > 0)
    begin

        set @DiffDate = DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate)
        set @workingDate = dateadd(dd,@DiffDate,@WorkingDate)
    end
    -- if adding a day makes it a Saturday, add 2 more to get to Monday (and test to make sure the week doesn't start with a holiday)
    IF (DATENAME(dw , @workingDate) = 'Saturday')
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 2, @workingDate)
    END

    RETURN @workingDate
END
```

Comment: Can you share sample input and output?

Comment: And share what you have tried so far. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: So, what is the question? This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a static dates lookup table (you can find many guides on how to do this via google, such as https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and then add a column that signifies whether or not that date is a working day or a holiday.

Your function is then as simple as:

```
select min(DateValue) as NextWorkingDay
from DatesLookupTable
where DateValue > @GivenDate
    and WorkingDay = 1
```